# solving cubic eq without using derivatives

Tags: calculus, functions, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, cubics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh9Sv.png)

Hi, I had this question, but I'm unable to solve it without using derivatives, though I have the answer (which is $15.7$ approx). I would appreciate it if you could help me out how to get the answer without using derivatives. Thanks a lot.

**Question:**  The profit of a company can be modelled by the polynomial function $p(t)= -4t^3+10t^2+8t-6$, where $p$ is the profit, in thousands of dollars, and $t$ is the time in years. When will the company make their maximum profit of $18 000 $ $?

Comment: Why without derivatives ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, believe it or not, is actually $2$.

What you (probably) did was get the equation $-4t^3+10t^2+8t-6 = 18000$. However, this is not correct, because of the caveat in the problem statement. It says "$p$ is the profit *in thousands of dollars*."

So we express $18000$ as $18$, since we are in *thousands of dollars*. The equation is therefore $$-4t^3+10t^2+8t-6=18.$$

This simplifies to $4t^3-10t^2-8t+24.$ Note that we can divide by $2$ to get $2t^3-5t^2-4t+12$.

To solve this, use the [Rational Root Theorem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Rational_Root_Theorem). Checking $1, -1, 2, -2, \dots$ note that $t = 2$ is a solution by RRT.

Dividing $2t^3-5t^2-4t+12$ by $t-2$ gets $2t^2-t-6$. The two solutions to this are $t = 2$ and $t = -\frac{3}{2}$.

So the company will make their maximum profit in $2$ years.

Comment: Thanks a lot, ma G you da best!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Use the rational root theorem to solve $$-4t^3+10t^2+8t-24=0.$$

Comment: right thank you so much !!